# Create array of date pairs for next 10 days

Tags: python, datetime

I wrote the below function which successfully creates pairs of dates in the format I need. However, I'm fairly new to Python and feel there must be a way to make this easier to read. Can this code be improved?

```
def getNextTenDays():
    dates = []
    arrive = datetime.datetime.now()
    for n in range(1, 11):
        arrive += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        next_day = arrive + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        arrive_s = datetime.datetime.strftime(arrive, '%m/%d/%Y')
        next_day_s = datetime.datetime.strftime(next_day, '%m/%d/%Y')
        dates.append({'arrive': arrive_s, 'depart': next_day_s})
    return dates
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some helpful answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather that continuing to append to arrive, just use the `n` offset from 'today'.

You can also use call `strftime` from a `datetime` object directly, like so:

```
def getNextTenDays():
    dates = []
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    for n in range(1, 11):
        arrive = today + datetime.timedelta(days=n)
        next_day = today + datetime.timedelta(days=n+1)
        arrive_s = arrive.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        next_day_s = next_day.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        dates.append({'arrive': arrive_s, 'depart': next_day_s})
    return dates
```

If you are just going to return the strings, and throw away the actual date times you can do that in one go like so:

```
def getNextTenDays():
    dates = []
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    for n in range(1, 11):
        dates.append({
            'arrive': (today + datetime.timedelta(days=n)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y'),
            'depart': (today + datetime.timedelta(days=n+1)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y'),
        })
    return dates
```

For here its a simple step to making it a list comprehension:

```
def getNextTenDays():
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    return [
        {
            'arrive': (today + datetime.timedelta(days=n)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y'),
            'depart': (today + datetime.timedelta(days=n+1)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y'),
        }
        for n in range(1,11)
    ]
```

Comment: Outstanding. I like the middle example the best.

Comment: The final simplification is just `yield`ing the dates instead of building an array.